Output audio device keeps disconnecting
I've been using Ubuntu for a few days. There are 2 output audio devices connected to my PC.

HDMI/DisplayPort - Built-in Audio

Line Out - Built-in Audio. Although there is also another option showing:

Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio


Which I don't know what it is. The problem is the Line Out - Built-in Audio which is my headphones keeps disconnecting and the audio output switches to the HDMI port. When I say it keeps disconnecting I mean the option for Line Out - Built-in Audio completely vanishes from my PC. After some time it again appears and output automatically connects to my Headphones again.

